# Issue bundling javascript with gulp js

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm bundling my javascript files using the task runner gulp js, during the development of an application I'm noticing a certain issue.

When I add the new feature(reveal a password) script refuses to work because of the form modal script which can be seen below.

```
'use strict';

var modal__button = document.getElementById("enquiry-form-trigger");
var close__button = document.getElementById("close");

modal__button.addEventListener("click", function (){
    var modal = document.getElementById("modal-form");
    modal.classList.add("fadeIn");
    modal.style.visibility = "visible";
});

close__button.addEventListener("click", function (){
    var modal = document.getElementById("modal-form");
    modal.classList.remove("fadeIn");
    modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
});

 When the above script and this other script below

"use strict"

document.getElementById("password-reveal-modal").addEventListener("click", function (){
    var x = document.getElementById("password-modal");
    if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = "text";
    } else {
        x.type = "password";
    }
});
```

The password reveal feature doesn't work, but when I paste it in chrome's dev tools works perfectly.

I'm not sure why it wont work without pasting it into the dev tools, it's baffling me, I'm not sure if its my setup or if its the custom javascript.

This is my gulp file setup in case anyone wants to check it, I don't see an issue but Ive only been using gulp for about 3 or 4 months.

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
  sass = require("gulp-sass"),
  image = require("gulp-image"),
  concat = require("gulp-concat"),
  browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
  reload = browserSync.reload,
  minifyEjs = require("gulp-minify-ejs"),
  stripEJSComments = require('gulp-strip-comments'),
  nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon'),
  plumber = require("gulp-plumber"),
  ejs = require("ejs"),
  uglify = require("gulp-uglify");


//Build task 
gulp.task("build", ["ejs", "styles", "images", "javascript", "routes", "models", "middleware"], function () {
  console.log("Build Success");
});

//start up sequence tasks
gulp.task('init', ["nodemon"], function () {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'http://localhost:2000', //Index.js port number
    port: 2128, // The port browser sync runs on 
    serveStatic: [ './public/', "./assets/"], // What files browser sync should have access to 
    reloadOnRestart: true, // Enable auto reload  
    ghostMode:false, //Stops session mirroring 
    open: "external", //Opens up on an external address (xxx.xxx.x.xx:3128)
  });
});

//Starts the express server
gulp.task('nodemon', function (done) {
  var running = false; //Default State

  return nodemon({
    script: 'index.js', //Index file for the JS project
    watch: ["./assets/", "./public/"] //What nodemon has access to
  })

    .on('start', function () {
      if (!running) {
        done();
      }
      running = true;
    })

    //Minor Delay Of 500ms Upon Restart
    .on('restart', function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        reload();
      }, 500);
    });
});

//SCSS Task
gulp.task("styles", function () {

  gulp.src("./assets/stylesheet/APP.scss")

  .pipe(plumber())

  .pipe(sass({
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
  }))


  .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/stylesheet/"))

  .pipe(browserSync.stream({ stream: true }));
});

//Compiles the express route/s
gulp.task("routes", function () {

   gulp.src([
        "./assets/routes/*.js"
    ])

    .pipe(plumber())

    .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/routes/"))

    .pipe(browserSync.stream({ stream: true }));
});


//Compiles the express route/s
gulp.task("models", function () {
  gulp.src("./assets/models/*.js")
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/models/"))
  .pipe(browserSync.stream({ stream: true }));
});


//Image minification
gulp.task("images", function () {
  return gulp.src("./assets/images/*")
    .pipe(image())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/images"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream({ stream: true }));
});

//Client javascript
gulp.task("javascript", function () {
  gulp.src([
    "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "./node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "./assets/scripts/**/**/*.js"
  ])
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(concat("main.js"))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/scripts/"))
  .pipe(browserSync.stream({ stream: true }));
});

//Middleware task
gulp.task("middleware", function () {
    gulp.src("./assets/middleware/*.js")
    .pipe(plumber())  
    .pipe(concat("index.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/middleware/"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream({ stream: true }));
});

//EJS task
gulp.task("ejs", function () {
    gulp.src("./assets/views/**/*.ejs")
    .pipe(plumber())  
    .pipe(stripEJSComments())
    .pipe(minifyEjs({}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/views"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream({ stream: true }));
});


//Default task array
gulp.task("default", ["init", "build"], function (done) {
  gulp.watch("./assets/stylesheet/**/*.scss", ["styles"]);
  gulp.watch("./assets/scripts/*", ["javascript"]);
  gulp.watch("./assets/routes/*.js", ["routes"]);
  gulp.watch("./assets/models/*.js",["models"]);
  gulp.watch("./assets/images/*",["images"]);
  gulp.watch("./assets/views/**/*.ejs",["ejs"]);
  browserSync.reload();
  done();
});
```

The two files which are causing the issue are the only files as I have tested each files and its only these two files weirdly so something is causing it to clash.

If you want me to upload my project to github just let me know and I will upload the latest version to my update branch.

I have exhausted all my knowledge into this problem and I am completely stuck now.

If anyone could help a fellow developer out it would be greatly appreciated.

cheers,

alex

Answer (score 0):

I needed to ensure the DOM had fully loaded before the script could be executed.